# Gurobi reports unbounded model despite mathematical impossibility

Tags: mathematical-optimization, julia, linear-programming, gurobi, julia-jump

I'm using Julia's wonderful JuMP package to solve a linear program with Gurobi 6.0.4 as a solver.
The objective function is a sum of decision variables, clearly defined as nonnegative, and the problem requires it to be minimized. For some reason, Gurobi thinks the model is unbounded.

Here is the definition of the variables and the objective:

```
@defVar(model, delta2[i=irange,j=pair[i]] >= 0)
@setObjective(model, Min, sum{delta2[i,j], i=irange, j=pair[i]})
```

Strange observation #1: although this is a minimization problem, the log for Gurobi's BarrierSolve method clearly shows the objective function increasing at each iteration. In addition, Gurobi seems to pull a switcheroo between the number of rows and the number of columns. Before the presolve step, the model has 50k rows and 25k columns. After the presolve step (which removes less than 1k rows and columns), we have 24k rows and 50k columns. The log looks like this:

```
Optimize a model with 50422 rows, 24356 columns and 1846314 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range    [1e-04, 2e+00]
  Objective range [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range    [9e-02, 2e+02]
  RHS range       [6e+00, 4e+03]
Presolve removed 164 rows and 635 columns
Presolve time: 0.79s
Presolved: 24192 rows, 49787 columns, 1836247 nonzeros
Ordering time: 1.60s
```

Strange observation #2: BarrierSolve eventually terminates with the status `InfeasibleOrUnbounded`. It then suggests setting `InfUnbdInfo=1` and using Gurobi's homogeneous BarrierSolve method by setting `BarHomogeneous=1`. When I do both of these things, the objective function keeps increasing(!) and the barrier log looks like this:

```
                      Objective                Residual
Iter       Primal          Dual         Primal    Dual     Compl     Time
   0  -6.95693531e+06  1.94975493e+02  1.10e+01 9.79e+02  1.39e+03     4s
   1  -3.18487510e+06  7.02065119e+06  5.50e-01 5.57e+02  3.45e+02     5s
   2  -8.43175324e+05  2.31465924e+06  4.81e-02 1.60e+02  9.32e+01     6s
   3  -2.37967254e+05  6.66124613e+05  6.51e-03 3.69e+01  2.35e+01     8s
   4  -7.49693243e+04  1.81252940e+05  1.64e-03 9.49e+00  6.46e+00     9s
   5  -3.20211009e+04  8.98339452e+04  6.25e-04 5.30e+00  3.11e+00    10s
   6  -1.04312874e+04  5.17677474e+04  2.06e-04 3.06e+00  1.65e+00    11s
   7   4.58252702e+02  4.04538611e+04  1.24e-04 2.19e+00  1.23e+00    12s
   8   3.40831629e+04  5.42543944e+04  7.65e-05 1.87e+00  1.54e+00    13s
   9   3.10110459e+05  2.25902448e+05  5.50e-05 1.87e+00  6.81e+00    15s
  10   1.59299448e+06  9.88980682e+05  5.73e-05 1.85e+00  3.37e+01    16s
  11*  1.88981433e+07  1.28711401e+07  2.93e-06 6.92e-01  1.14e-03    17s
  12*  1.65096505e+08  3.73470456e+08  5.57e-06 5.73e-02  1.40e-04    18s
  13*  7.18252597e+09  3.21890978e+09  2.62e-06 2.01e-03  4.60e-06    20s
  14*  1.15822505e+12  7.53575462e+10  1.50e-05 6.18e-06  8.50e-09    21s
  15*  1.08512896e+13  2.57735417e+12  2.92e-06 6.99e-08  1.22e-10    22s
  16*  3.03152292e+14  7.54681485e+13  1.21e-07 7.50e-10  1.28e-12    23s

Barrier performed 16 iterations in 23.41 seconds
Unbounded model
```

I don't understand how a linear program can be unbounded when it involves the minimization of a sum of nonnegative variables. Is this an issue with Gurobi or did I do something wrong in setting up the LP ? I suspect it might be some sort of numerical error, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

EDIT: I found a partial fix to the problem by loosening some constraints and making the feasibility region artificially better. It seems the problem was really a feasibility issue and not an unboundedness issue, which means Gurobi might actually have been referring to an unboundedness of the dual ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post more of the code? Also, can you try putting an upper bound on the variables just to confirm it is unbounded?

Comment: Also, which Gurobi version? You could also try writing the model to an LP file to make 100% sure there is nothing weird going on.

Comment: The `Bounds range    [9e-02, 2e+02]` suggests that there might be other variables?

Comment: There are indeed other variables, but I don't understand why it should matter… The bottom line is that the only variables present in the objective function are necessarily nonnegative and so unboundedness doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh I appreciate that, but something non-obvious is happening so I'm just trying to figure out where the error is.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a numerical issue, but I don't understand what Gurobi is playing at with its unboundedness/infeasibility charades.

Comment: Can you please try forcing it to use the simplex method? Do you have range constraints with a very narrow range?

Comment: The rest of the LP is pretty complex and there is a lot going on so I'm not sure you want to peruse through the whole code.

Comment: I tried forcing it to use simplex but it is poorly suited for this particular LP and it doesn't really converge. And yes, I do have many range constraints with a very narrow range! It is precisely relaxing the tightness of these constraints that removes this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is poorly conditioned due to "narrow" range constraints. If they really need to be range constraints, consider rescaling your problem. If they are more like "approximate" equality constraints, consider adding a slack variable and making it an actual equality constraint, and put a penalty on the slacks in the objective.